# Jekyll/SASS site not compiling via Ruby running on Windows 7, tested also with Prepros, site a no go

Tags: ruby, html, sass, jekyll, prepros

I have Jekyll 2.4.0 and Ruby 2.0.09576 installed.

I am working along with Travis from YouTube channel 'DevTips' and using all of his files/information to compile his 'Artist' project site. Last week I successfully served the project site via Ruby/Jekyll serve from source folder. Today, I tried the same process and the site would not compile. I am using same localhost:8000, that is verified and worked last week. I am running Win7 64bit and followed advice to run UTF-8 encoding command: chcp 65001.

No files have changed in the portfolio folder on my PC, NO windows updates or other software installed. The other thing on jekyllrb.com/windows/ says is to add a line of code for 'Auto-regeneration' to the 'Gemfile'...OK, it does not say where this 'Gemfile' is to edit...is it here?: C:.../RubyDevKit/bin/gem.windows batch file?

I am stumped as to why the project files compiled and displayed just fine last week and today it does not work, NO connection can be made to localhost:8000...so no site generated. I also tried to view view site via Prepros, using their 'Open Live Preview' and that generates a site on localhost:8001 displaying only this text: --- --- {% include header.html %} {% include about.html %} {% include work.html %} {% include clients.html %} {% include contact.html %} {% include form.html %} {% include footer.html %}

I've tried other localhost addresses...8000 through 8005.

Any ideas?

Thank you!
Mark

Comment: Are you intending to publish your site on GitHub? If that's the case, `Gemfile` can be generated to lock dependencies in sync with GitHub and I can explain how to do this.

Comment: Downvote...?? I am new to this site and new to using framework software and GitHub is a bit confusing to me. I intend on establishing myself in the Front-end developer realm and yes, I intend on publishing some with GitHub. Any help in this regard would be fantastic! Thank you for the time! I've not yet discovered where this 'Gemfile' is, but I do understand I need to edit it...please enlighten me!

Comment: Got it, thanks 'D-side' and 'Jeff Bridgman'...I am new to this and have deleted my 'non' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the localhost adress? 
Default localhost for jekyll is 4000.

Also Prepros live preview will not work in your jekyll folder, because the acutal site is 
rendered within the _site-folder. This folder is what jekyll serve generates.

So can you maybe access the site over localhost:4000 and/or is the _site-folder there? Or does jekyll just not work at all?

Comment: OK, just to establish one thing...I've already ran/served the demo site successfully via Ruby, running 'jekyll serve' from the site folder--last week, nothing changed on my PC as it sat off over the weekend, then I tried to run site again and jekyll does do it's thing in Ruby, I can even end the server session 'CTRL + C' and it stops, but no site is shown on localhost, no error messages. I tried localhost:4000, no go. I've edited the _config.yml in site folder to ensure port used is: 8002. I loaded all site files into Prepros and then tried the 'live preview'...that did not work either.

Comment: Could you maybe show the complete output in your CMD, when you run jekyll serve?

Comment: I've not found a way to paste in the command line code snippet here and that's a problem. I like the concept of help with this site, but for the life of me the simple task of snipping/pasting code from anything is more than annoying. Thanks for the attention here, I will proceed on my own, much appreciated!

Comment: You could just upload a screenshot somewhere and attach it here :)

Comment: OK, this sounds elementary, but I did try this and it would not paste into the comment box, I even researched how this might be done and sad to say I am out of ideas other than to type out the output code, which is long/tedius...I am all ears for ideas on how to simply paste a screen shot of code here...thank you!

Comment: As far as I konw you can't upload pictures here, so you need to upload it somewhere else, and then just copy paste the link to the picture.s

Comment: Did a quck google search, here's how you can copy the output from the cmd, then just paste it here. _Alternatively, right-click anywhere inside the command window, select Mark from the contextual menu, use the mouse to highlight a block text and then press Enter to save it to the clipboard._

Comment: PART 1 OF OUTPUT: C:\Users\Turd Ferguson\Desktop\portfolio>chcp 65001 Active code page: 65001
C:\Users\Turd Ferguson\Desktop\portfolio>jekyll serve --watch Configuration file: C:/Users/Turd Ferguson/Desktop/portfolio/_config.yml Source: C:/Users/Turd Ferguson/Desktop/portfolio Destination: C:/Users/Turd Ferguson/Desktop/portfolio/_site Generating... done. Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes: require 'rbconfig' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/i gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' end

Comment: Part 2: Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/Turd Ferguson/Desktop/portfolio' Configuration file: C:/Users/Turd Ferguson/Desktop/portfolio/_config.yml jekyll 2.4.0 | Error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network a ddress/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2) E, [2014-11-05T13:21:52.499216 #1168] ERROR -- : Actor crashed! Celluloid::DeadActorError: attempted to call a dead actor C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/re sponses.rb:29:in value'

Comment: Part 3:  C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ca lls.rb:92:invalue' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/pr oxies/sync_proxy.rb:33:in method_missing' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/director y.rb:8:inscan' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/change.r b:38:in change' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ca lls.rb:26:inpublic_send' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ca lls.rb:26:in dispatch'

Comment: Part 4: /2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ca lls.rb:63:indispatch' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ce ll.rb:60:in block in invoke' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ce ll.rb:71:inblock in task' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ac tor.rb:357:in block in task' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ta sks.rb:57:inblock in initialize' C:/RubyDevKit/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/ta sks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I will be buying 'Mixture' front end developer framework software! Enough of the bugs and wasted time coming mostly from lame Windows software issues!

CHEERS!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [latest version](https://www.python.org/downloads/) of Python Installed? I had the same issue but after installing python's latest update (2.7.9) the issue was resolved.